# What is this component called?

Tags: resistors, components, identification

I recently bought an old coffee maker but it doesn't work. Everytime I switch it on my earth circuit breaker goes off so my whole house doesn't have electricity. I already looked on google to find something similar to it. I think it might be a thermal resistor, but I don't know how to test it and if it's broken how to get the right part again because I can't read what was written on it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a thermal fuse, likely something else is wrong with that device.

Comment: That is a thermal cutout device.  It will open if the temperature exceeds the cut off value.

Comment: @DwayneReid so this component makes sure the water boiler doesn't get too hot right?

Comment: The thermal fuse didn't blow but the main house breaker did. So the short circuit must be before it reaches the coil.

Comment: @DB93 Yes - it is a safety component that will permanently disable the device when it becomes tripped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the Electronics SE.

The device you picture is a thermal fuse (aka thermal cutoff). It is not what is causing your problem. All it can do is cut off the power, and it does that only once and stays open (there is a bit of material inside that melts and the device opens up). It must be replaced with a similar type with the same melting temperature (usually marked on the side). It's purpose is to keep your house from burning down. Yours is probably fine or the machine wouldn't be blowing your breaker. [Here](http://www.cantherm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/SDF_JUNE_2016.pdf) is a datasheet showing typical models.

[image]

Most likely your heater has **shorted internally**, perhaps to ground. That would typically mean it's unrepairable economically because a replacement heater would be too costly, at least for a cheap coffee maker. If it's a $2K Faema commercial cappuccino maker, then of course it will be repairable. There are other possibilities such as a bad MOV or capacitor if there is electronics in the coffee maker.

**Be extremely careful** working with this, if the heater has shorted to ground, a faulty ground wire could cause mains voltage to appear on the housing of the kettle, which could result in a (possibly fatal) electrical shock to someone touching the housing.

The ground connection and the thermal fuse are both safety considerations that are not involved in actually boiling your water or controlling the normal shut-off, they are there to make sure a failure inside the coffee maker does not result in damage or injury.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a thermal cutout fuse. 
Its purpose is as a final failsafe when the machine becomes defective. If the boiler becomes too hot (due to malfunction, not 'too hot' as in the water hast started boiling and the machine may turn off) it will become an open circuit and prevent more power flowing into the heating element. This is a one-time thing, when it goes open, it will stay open forever. It can be replaced, but it is very important to make sure that the fuse did not trigger because of a fault when you do - in that case you would just allow the fault to become a hazard again.

As the device in this case has not shown an open, but is tripping breakers, this is not what is going on. The device is likely internally defective and should be replaced.

Comment: If an earth circuit breaker tripped, look for a wire or some other live part that has made contact with a part that is connected to earth.